# Pros and Cons of using ConcurrencyMode.Multiple in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am new to WCF. I have a WCF where many application using this service. And my requirement is, WCF service should handle multiple request at the same time. I know that this can be acheived by using `[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]`.

But I want to know what are the pros and cons of implementing Multiple option, as my service deals with payment processing. And I guess default `ConcurrencyMode` is `Single`. Can anyone please guide me by your suggestions?

As far as I surfed, everyone suggesting if we use `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple`, we are responsible for providing the necessary synchronization/thread safety. I am bit confused, what kind of issues may occur and what are the steps needed to overcome when using `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` and `InstanceContextMode.PerCall`?

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrencyMode.Multiple can cause scalability issues and may cause threading issues as mentioned in the SO link - [ConcurrencyMode.Multiple in stateless WCF services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517143/concurrencymode-multiple-in-stateless-wcf-services).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you consider reviewing the following "*Concurrency Management*" excerpt from the “*Programming WCF Services*” book:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521301-02-08.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The following articles might provide more information on the subject...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickrain/archive/2009/06/15/wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-1.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and