# how to prevent wcf multiple requests with the same data?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a wcf méthode like this :

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UpdateMyData", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "updateMyDataResponse")]
    UpdateMyDataResponse UpdateMyData(UpdateMyDataRequest updateMyDataRequest);
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    //1. i want this methode not callable with the same data in the request
    //2. or i want it callable only once at a time by the client
    //means the client must wait the end of the first request to send the seconde
    //3. or i want the client to be able to call the entire service request by request
    public UpdateMyDataResponse
    UpdateMyData(UpdateMyDataRequest updateMyDataRequest)
    {
        var fileName = updateMyDataRequest.fileName;

        //Never Go her with the same filename value for all the service's insatnces
        //or never go her for the same client twice in the same time

        //Heavy work
        //...

        return new UpdateMyDataResponse(true);
    }
}
```

i have found tow possible solutions.

### **1. Use service instance per session, and limit the connections of the client to 1**

This issue is a security one. that means the calls for the data of the same client can comme from multiple IP.
And i'm not sur i can make my boss accept this solution

### **2. Use static list in the service class, and store the file names in process.**

This solution is apparently a bad practice.
And i'm not sure i'm going to convince, either.

can anyone give me an advice or a link ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use InstanceContextMode.Single or InstanceContextMode.PerCall.

**useful link:** 
[WCF Concurrency (Single, Multiple and Reentrant) and Throttling](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shivprasadk/wcf-concurrency-single-multiple-and-reentrant-and-throttling/)

 [**Sessions, Instancing, and Concurrency**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/sessions-instancing-and-concurrency?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

 http://www.wcftutorial.net/Per-Call-Service.aspx

 https://stackoverflow.com/a/60767182/17218587